# How can I hide a cell of a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I would like to put data as shown below into Cell(2) but hidden and only using pure JS

```
for(var i = 0;  i < obj.features.length; i++) {
    var featureTitle = obj.features[i].properties.title;
    var featureHab = obj.features[i].properties.Broad_Habi;

    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<a href="#" class="myButtonView" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">?</a>';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<a href="#" class="myButtonDelete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">X</a>';
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= featureTitle;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= featureHab;
}
```

Comment: Why in pure JS?
In jQuery you can use : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @aGer Yes i saw many JQuery solutions but i am totally new to this so i have now idear have to add jQuery to my code above if you can help me with this that would be awesome

Comment: @aGer Why suggest jQuery? It's not the cure to everything and it's good to understand what jQuery is doing under the hood, i.e., how to write vanilla JS.

Comment: KISS = Keep it simple and smart.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions for this

In JavaScript, it's as simple as using visibility-hidden.

```
var tableCel = document.querySelector('td')[2];
tableCell.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

If you later want to show the table cell, you simply change the value of the property.

```
tableCell.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

In jQuery, there are a couple of ways

```
$("td:eq(2)").hide();
```

Or

```
$("td:eq(2)").css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
```

Comment: Sorry that i am asking but i am rally new to javascript how would i apply the first solution to my code

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to hide on clicking of deleteRow which can be possible like this

```
function deleteRow(rowyouwanttohide)
{
    rowyouwanttohide.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    //or you can go to display none like below
    rowyouwanttohide.style.display= 'none'; 
}
```

Comment: just what I needed